# Loading php-extension in Symfony2 - connecting to SAP

Tags: php, symfony, php-extension, saprfc

As a first question here, I'll start with something hard!

I am working on a Symfony project that can link with SAP to extract data and do some reporting. I used the [sapnwrfc](https://github.com/piersharding/php-sapnwrfc) extension from piersharding, as it is one of the only that can be compiled with my environment (windows x86 and php 5.6.8).

The first steps worked not so badly :

- add the dll files to php/ext
- add the line php-sapnwrfc-x86.dll to php.ini
- it appears on phpinfo()
- make it work in a sample file outside of symfony (standalone php script) with this kind of code:

**/test.php**

```
 <? php
 require_once 'sap_config.php';
 require_once 'spyc.php';
 extension_loaded("sapnwrfc");
 global $SAP_CONFIG;
 class _
 {
     public function setUp() {
         global $SAP_CONFIG;
         $this->config = Spyc::YAMLLoad($SAP_CONFIG);
     }

     public function sapConnect() {
         try {
             $this->conn = new sapnwrfc($this->config);
         }
         ....
```

- So I tried something similar in a Symfony project, but this error appears :

  > "Attempted to load class "sapnwrfc" from the global namespace.
  >   Did you forget a "use" statement?"

with this code :

**/src/myBundle/Extensions/SapConnection.php**

```
<?php

namespace SE\InputBundle\Extensions;

use SE\InputBundle\Extensions\SapConfig;
use SE\InputBundle\Extensions\Spyc;
use SE\InputBundle\Entity\SAPRF;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

//the following doesn't seem to do much:
extension_loaded("sapnwrfc");

use sapnwrfc;
use sapnwrfcConnectionException;
use sapnwrfcCallException;

global $SAP_CONFIG;

class SapConnection
{
    public function setUp() {
        global $SAP_CONFIG;
        $this->config = Spyc::YAMLLoad($SAP_CONFIG);
        //the following displays "false"
        $alertpop = (class_exists("sapnwrfc")) ? "true" : "false";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$alertpop');</script>";
    }

    public function sapConnect() {
        try {
            // the error is triggered here
            $this->conn = new sapnwrfc($this->config);
        }
        catch (sapnwrfcConnectionException $e) {
            echo "Exception type: ".$e."<br />";
            echo "Exception key: ".$e->key."<br />";
            echo "Exception code: ".$e->code."<br />";
            echo "Exception message: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Exception type: ".$e."\n";
            echo "Exception key: ".$e->key."\n";
            echo "Exception code: ".$e->code."\n";
            echo "Exception message: ".$e->getMessage();
            throw new Exception('Connection failed.');
        }    
    }

.....
```

and of course it doesn't work either if I remove the use statement... 
Google isn't a big help as this seems pretty specific. Do you  have an idea?
Would it be a compatibility issue between symfony and the php-extension, or do I have to notify Symfony to use this class as a php-extension? Or is it somewhere in my project config that I did something wrong?

Let me know if you would like more details!

Comment: Welcome to SO. The way you have written this, PHP is trying to find this extension within the `Extensions` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
use \sapnwrfc;
use \sapnwrfcConnectionException;
use \sapnwrfcCallException;
```

You are missing `\`, which leads to php searching for these classes in the current namespace, which is `Extensions`. (The first line in your code.)

Also, you need to escpae your classes/exceptions.

```
public function sapConnect() {
    try {
        // the error is triggered here
        $this->conn = new \sapnwrfc($this->config);
    }
    catch (\sapnwrfcConnectionException $e) {
        echo "Exception type: ".$e."<br />";
        echo "Exception key: ".$e->key."<br />";
        echo "Exception code: ".$e->code."<br />";
        echo "Exception message: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception type: ".$e."\n";
        echo "Exception key: ".$e->key."\n";
        echo "Exception code: ".$e->code."\n";
        echo "Exception message: ".$e->getMessage();
        throw new \Exception('Connection failed.');
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you @web-nomad for the rapid answer.
Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue. The error thrown by symfony is the same : the function is not recognized in the global namespace. I doubt we can go higher than the global namespace though.
The little alert still displays "false" too.
Thanks

Comment: Can you print `$SAP_CONFIG` in the `setUp` method and see if has the proper values.

Comment: Yes it has. It is an array with the following keys : 'ASHOST' => '...',
            'SYSNR' => '00',
            'CLIENT' => '200',
            'user' => '...',
            'passwd' => '...',
            'LANG' => 'en',
            'TRACE' => 1,
            'LOGLEVEL' => 'warn'